# Applying a Kalman filter on a leg follower robot

Tags: kalman-filter

I was asked to create a leg follower robot (I already did it) and in the second part of this assignment I have to develop a Kalman filter in order to improve the following process of the robot. The robot gets from the person the distance where she is to the robot and also the angle (it is a relative angle, because the reference is the robot itself, not absolute x-y coordinates)

About this assignment I have a serious doubt. Everything I have read, every sample I have seen about kalman filter has been in one dimension (a car running distance or a rock falling from a building) and according to the task I would have to apply it in 2 dimensions. Is it possible to apply  a kalman filter like this?

If it is possible to calculate kalman filter in 2 dimensions then I would understand that what is asked to do is to follow the legs in a linnearized way, despite a person walks weirdly (with random movements) --> About this I have the doubt of how to establish the function of the state matrix, could anyone please tell me how to do it or to tell me where I can find more information about this?

Comment: The Kalman filter can be applied to an n-dimensional problem, so that is not a limitation. You have to find out what the motion model is for your leg robot. If it is nonlinear, you can try to apply the extended Kalman filter. For example, what is a "leg follower" robot? A robot that follows a human's legs? Is it a robot with legs that follows a line? Is it a robot attached to human legs and estimate the position?

Without any further information about your problem, it is difficult to pinpoint your specific issue, and I hesitate to link you to the wikipedia article on the Kalman filter.

Answer (score 1):

Well you should read up on Kalman Filter. Basically what it does is estimate a state through its mean and variance separately. The state can be whatever you want. You can have local coordinates in your state but also global coordinates.

Note that the latter will certainly result in nonlinear system dynamics, in which case you could use the Extended Kalman Filter, or to be more correct the continuous-discrete Kalman Filter, where you treat the system dynamics in a continuous manner and the measurements in discrete time.

Example with global coordinates:

Assuming you have a small cubic mass which can drive forward with velocity v. You could simply model the dynamics in local coordinates only, where your state s would be `s = [v]`, which is a linear model.

But, you could also incorporate the global coordinates x and y, assuming we are moving on a plane only. Then you would have `s = [x, y, phi, v]'`. We need `phi` to keep track of the current orientation since the cube can only move forward in respect to its orientation of course. Let's define `phi` as the angle between the cube's forward direction and the `x`-axis. Or in other words: With `phi=0` the cube would move along the x-axis, with `phi=90°` it would move along the y-axis.

The **nonlinear system dynamics with global coordinates** can then be written as

```
s_dot = [x_dot, y_dot, phi_dot, v_dot]'
```

with

```
x_dot = cos(phi) * v
y_dot = sin(phi) * v
phi_dot = ...
v_dot = ... (Newton's Law)
```

In **EKF (Extended Kalman Filter) Prediction step** you would use the (discretized) equations above to predict the mean of the state in the first step of and the linearized (and discretized) equations for prediction of the Variance.

There are two things to keep in mind when you decide what your state vector `s` should look like:

- You might be tempted to use my linear example `s = [v]` and then integrate the velocity outside of the Kalman Filter in order to obtain the global coordinate estimates. This would work, but you would lose the awesomeness of the Kalman Filter since you would only integrate the mean of the state, not its variance. In other words, you would have no idea what the current uncertainties for your global coordinates are.
- The second step of the Kalman Filter, the measurement or correction update, requires that you can describe your sensor output as a function of your states. So you may have to add states to your representation just so that you can express your measurements correctly `as z[k] = h(s[k], w[k])` where `z` are measurements and `w` is a noise vector with Gaussian distribution.